# Почему вылетает :OnErrorNotImplementedException: The mapper function returned a null value

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, rxandroid

Пытаюсь получить данные из БД, но вылетает ошибка

> io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The mapper function returned a null value.

Класс данных, в который должен вкачаться List со всеми объектами из БД:

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {
@SerializedName("Data")
protected T data;
public T getData() { return data;}
```

Часть интерфейса, отвечающая за получение этого Листа (интерфейс, указанный для создания Retrofit) :

```
@Headers({"Authorization: Basic NTlkY2M1YzVhNGJlMjA1ODZkMsYwZTgzOjE2NWM2MjNhNDI=",
            "X-Api-Factory-Application-Id: 59dgc5c5a4be20586d260e83"})
    @GET("db/Usage")
    Observable<BaseResponse<List<Usage>>> getUsageResponse();
```

В постмане работает. Kjub OkHttp видят полученный объект JSON. Создание ретрофита:

```
protected UsageDBInterface restService;

protected Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(this.BASE_URL)
        .client(provideClient())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();

protected OkHttpClient provideClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();
}

protected UsageDBInterface getRestService(){
    if (restService==null) restService = retrofit.create(UsageDBInterface.class);
    return restService;
}
```

Метод, обеспечивающий доступ приложения к слою данных:

```
public ArrayList getCategoryUsageList() {

    Observable<ArrayList<Usage>> observableList;
    ArrayList<Usage> result = new ArrayList<>();
    restService.getUsageResponse().map(BaseResponse::getData)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(resultList->{
                result.addAll(resultList);
               });
    return result;
}
```

На основе данного ArrayList адаптер должен прорисовывать РеасайклерВью фрагмента, но на этом этапе как раз возникает Exception. Как исправить?  Кстати, поля класса Usage тоже снабжены аннотациями @SerializedName, геттерами и сеттерами для соответствующих полей.

UPD Ответ Сервера

```
D/OkHttp: {"fields":

{"usagesIds":{"name":"usagesIds","type":"string","array":true,"populate":false,"ref":"59dccc66a4be20586d260e8c"},

"name":{"name":"name","type":"string"}},

"count":4,

"data":

[{"name":"Еда","usagesIds":[""],"id":"59dce6f7a4be20586d260e95"},{"name":"Бензин","usagesIds":[""],"id":"59dce70ea4be20586d260e96"},{"name":"Коммунальные расходы","usagesIds":""],"id":"59dce70fa4be20586d260e97"},{"name":"На жизнь","usagesIds":["59dce70ea4be20586d260e96","59dce6f7a4be20586d260e95","59dce70fa4be20586d260e97"],"id":"59dce71ba4be20586d260e98"}]}
```

Comment: Какую версию rxJava используете? Первую или вторую? Во второй нельзя эмитить null.

Comment: вторую... мне нужно понять, почему он выдает null. Вроде сделал все как указано в интернет примерах, но результат - exception.

Comment: Если у вас `BaseResponse::getData` выдаёт `null` то, видимо, вы неправильно модель данных описали. Покажите ответ сервера в виде `JSON`

Comment: Указал в теле вопроса.. только как то кривовато получилось

Comment: Получается, что у вас ошибка в имени поля в модели. В JSON `data`, а у вас в аннотации `Data` указано.

Comment: спасибо, добрый человек...)) крашится перестало, но не работает так, как должно.. но это уже отдельная песня) Напишите тоже самое в ответе - отмечу как решение))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас ошибка в имени поля в модели. В JSON `data`, а в аннотации `Data` указано.

Answer (score 0):

Я не спец по Rx, но подозреваю, что проблема вот здесь:

```
restService.getUsageResponse().map(BaseResponse::getData)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(resultList->{
            result.addAll(resultList);
           });
```

Метод `BaseResponse::getData` возвращает `null`.

Comment: проблема здесь и есть... даже конкретнее: <br/>  `public final <R> Observable<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {  

        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(mapper, "mapper is null");  

        return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableMap<T, R>(this, mapper));  
    }`  

null возвращает `ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(mapper, "mapper is null");` Только я не пойму почему.